# Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker container with one of my nodejs project and when i try to build using docker it is showing an error and at first i thought it was because of the vulnerabilities in the npm dependencies but i fix the vulnerabilities but still the error occured

```
firstproject-api-1  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327
firstproject-api-1  |   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
firstproject-api-1  |                  ^
firstproject-api-1  |
firstproject-api-1  | Error: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/src/app/node_modules/onnxruntime-node/bin/napi-v3/linux/x64//libonnxruntime.so.1.15.1)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327:18)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
firstproject-api-1  |     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/onnxruntime-node/dist/binding.js:9:1)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
firstproject-api-1  |     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/onnxruntime-node/dist/backend.js:18:19)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
firstproject-api-1  |     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/onnxruntime-node/dist/index.js:21:19)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
firstproject-api-1  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10) {
firstproject-api-1  |   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
firstproject-api-1  | }
firstproject-api-1  |
firstproject-api-1  | Node.js v20.8.0
firstproject-api-1 exited with code 1
```

This is the error i got and i run npm rebuild  onnxruntime-node and also i added platform: linux/x86_64
to my service in docker compose file

**my Docker file**

``
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /var/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
``

**my Docker-compose**

version: '3'
services:
mymongo:
image: "mongo"

mynode:
build: .
ports:
- "3000:3000"

Comment: Please update the question by adding the content of your `Dockerfile`.